# Flash Debugger in Intellij IDEA

Tags: flash, debugging

I have created a flash project in Intellij IDEA, also I configured flash sdk. As I know, it has inbuilt flash debugger. 
But when I run my app, "trace()" is ignored. And I see in console "fdb is waiting". Why debugger doesn't work? Thank.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is because the radius of curvature of your hand is too huge

Comment: Try offering an answer that adds value to the question.